# Not getting any firebase cloud messaging notification when device comes online after offline in IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Iam using firebase cloud messaging to send push notification but iam getting push only when device is online and not getting when device comes to online from offline..even after few minutes of offline also push not getting.I have tried adding apps-expiration key also..but not working...Is anything else i have to do to make it work.